# How can i build one List<string> using a class with scalar values?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code for example that create a List

```
public static void CreateTextList(string filePath)
        {
            List<string> text;

            text = new List<string>();
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
            htmlDoc.Load(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));

            if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
            {
                var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/b");
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    text.Add(node.InnerText);
                }
            }
            TextList = Filters.filterNumbers(text);
        }
```

And i have another two methods that also create each one another List
But instead creating 3 Lists i want to create one List of all 3 values.

In top of form1 i added:

```
static List<string> test = new List<string>();
List<Name> list = new List<Name>();
```

In the bottom of form1 i added:

```
public class Name
        {
            public string First { get; set; }
            public string Middle { get; set; }
            public string Last { get; set; }
        }
```

Now i want in the method CreateTextList to do something like this:

```
public static void CreateTextList(string filePath)
        {
            List<string> text;

            text = new List<string>();
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
            htmlDoc.Load(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));

            if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
            {
                var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/b");
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    text.Add(node.InnerText);
                    test.Add(new Name { First = "Brian"});
                }
            }
            TextList = Filters.filterNumbers(text);
        }
```

What i added is:

```
test.Add(new Name { First = "Brian"});
```

But i'm getting error:

Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

Error   4   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.Name' to 'string'

First how to fix the errors and second how can i make it realy by the logic i want to build the test List ?
So it will take from each method the value and in the end i will have a List of First Middle Last, First Middle Last, First Middle Last...

Comment: test is list of string but you are trying to add Name object in it.

Comment: list.Add(new Name { First = "Brian"});text is List of String.

Comment: Either add a `string` value instead of `Name` object to list, or change the list declaration to be of type `List<Name>`. The 2nd seems more make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 3&4:You are Trying to Add an object(Name) to List of String .Its not possible.Second Change

```
test.Add(new Name { First = "Brian"});
to
list.Add(  new Name(){First = "First",Last = "LastName",Middle = "MiddleName"});
```

And then you can use Foreach at the end to loop through list,like this

```
foreach (var value in list)
            {
             //var firstname = value.First;   
            }
```

Comment: I changed it to list.Add but why when i'm doing in the first method: list.Add(new Name { First = test }); and then in the second method: list.Add(new Name { Middle = test1 }); and in the third method: list.Add(new Name { Last = test2 }); i see in the list List some indexs are null.  I guess in each method i have a loop so it will add to the First for example 50 items then in the Middle another 50 and also in Last 50. How can i make that it will Add each time an item from another method. Method 1 Method 2 Method 3 now add again the next itertion in each method: Methd 1 Methd 2 Methd 3.

Comment: And not to add first all 50 items then 50 then 50. But to add 1,1,1 then 2,2,2 then 3,3,3

Comment: @user3816441:you have defined your class Name with three properties(First,Middle,Last).So if you create a list of Name,once you assign value to one of your property,the others will be null.That is the reason you are seeing null for some index.and if you want a three different list of first,second,middle name.you got to sacrifice your Name Class(Not Recommended) and have a three different list of type string having value of First,Middle,Last Names.i.e like List<String> First;List<String>Middle,List<String>Last;